# hosting rails site on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Trying to deploy my rails site to heroku. 
i've made sure to commit everything, raked after i pushed etc. it all seems to work, however, i got an application error when i try to open my site on heroku, even though it worked on local.

Heroku logs:

```
2013-01-29T16:08:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in block (2 levels) in with' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in block (2 levels) in with'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb:1:in `'

2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in block in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in load_dependency' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in require_or_load' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in block in constantize' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in block in run_initializers' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in depend_on' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in require_dependency' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in block (2 levels) in eager_load!' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in block in eager_load!' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in run_initializers' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in initialize!' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in method_missing' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:inblock in ' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in instance_eval' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in initialize' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:in new' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:in' 
2013-01-29T16:08:13+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=team-van.herokuapp.com fwd=18.189.116.76 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in const_missing' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in eval' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in app' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in app' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in wrapped_app' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in start' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in start' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in block in ' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in tap' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in ' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in eager_load!' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in instance_exec' 
2013-01-29T16:08:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in block in assign_attributes': unknown attribute: category (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError) 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in assign_attributes' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in initialize' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/restaurant.rb:49:in new' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/restaurant.rb:49:inblock in ' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1792:in each' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1208:inblock in foreach' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1354:in open' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1207:inforeach' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/restaurant.rb:48:in <top (required)>' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in block in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in load_dependency' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in require_or_load' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in load_missing_constant' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in block in const_missing' 
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in
```

My model/restaurant.rb

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :activity, :category, :age, :budget, 
    :description, :info_url, :name, :rating, 
    :size, :tag, :time, :tourist, :location

  scope :lunch, where("category = 'l'")
  scope :dinner, where("category = 'd'")

  scope :boston, where("location = 'b'")
  scope :newyork, where("location = 'nyc'")
  scope :sanfran, where("location = 'sf'")

  scope :b1, order("budget asc")
  scope :b2, where("budget <=2").order("budget desc")
  scope :b3, order("budget desc")

  scope :g1, order("size asc")
  scope :g2, where("size <=2").order("size desc")
  scope :g3, order("size desc")

  scope :a1, order("age asc")
  scope :a2, where("age <=2").order("age desc")
  scope :a3, order("age desc")

  scope :l1, order("activity asc")
  scope :l2, where("activity <=2").order("activity desc")
  scope :l3, order("activity desc")

  scope :t1, order("tourist asc")
  scope :t2, where("tourist <=2").order("tourist desc")
  scope :t3, order("tourist desc")

  scope :rate, order("rating desc")

  def self.lsearching(b,g,a,l,t,loc)
    @lrestaurants = eval ("Restaurant." + "lunch." + b + "." + g + "." + a + "." + l + "." + t + "." + loc)
    #@restaurants = Restaurant.rate
  end
  def self.dsearching(b,g,a,l,t, loc)
    @drestaurants = eval ("Restaurant." + "dinner." + b + "." + g + "." + a + "." + l + "." + t + "." + loc)

  end

end

require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('app/assets/nycrestaurant.csv',  "r:ISO-8859-1") do |row|
  record = Restaurant.new(
    :name   => row[0], 
    :category => row[1],
    :description => row[11],
    :info_url => row[3],
    :time => row[4],
    :size => row[5],
    :activity => row[6],
    :budget => row[7],
    :age => row[8],
    :tourist => row[9],
    :rating => row[10],
    :tag => row[11],
    :location => row[12]
  )
  record.save!
end

CSV.foreach('app/assets/bostonrest.csv',  "r:ISO-8859-1") do |row|
  record = Restaurant.new(
    :name   => row[0], 
    :category => row[11],
    :description => row[1],
    :info_url => row[3],
    :time => row[4],
    :size => row[5],
    :activity => row[6],
    :budget => row[7],
    :age => row[8],
    :tourist => row[9],
    :rating => row[10],
    :tag => row[2],
    :location => row[12]
  )
  record.save!
end
```

Comment: What's in RestaurantsController?  Looks like a syntax error at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

You need run the migrations on heroku, at console run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And you need to learn to read logs! Look here:

```
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in block in assign_attributes': unknown attribute: category (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in each'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in assign_attributes'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in initialize'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/restaurant.rb:49:in new'
2013-01-29T16:08:10+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/restaurant.rb:49:inblock
```

The message `unknown attribute: category` means that the database doesn't have the column category.

And last, format the log message before posting here, we appreciate.

Comment: yeah i went through all the logs, deleted all the redundant migrations, and still had the same error. tried pretty much everything i could find online. thanks though.

Comment: It's seems that you have more problems, like `/app/app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb:1:in '`, but it's hard to guess what can cause this. Search at your log file search for files  how is in your project, like controller, models, configuration, routes...